# Ekert's QKD protocol with Eve ( hacker ) sending random mixture of qubit pairs in the states |00>, |11>, |++>, |-->

Tags: qkd

Before starting my question, the problem is from the book *"Quantum Computing, A Gentle Introduction". Ex 3.15*

**The context of the problem is the following:**
We suppose Eve can pose as the entity sending the purported EPR pairs;
Eve sends a random mixture of qubit pairs in the states $$|00\rangle, |11\rangle, |++\rangle, |--\rangle$$ instead of sending EPR pairs.

*(1)* After Alice and Bob perform the Ekert 91 protocol, on how many bits on average do their purported shared secret keys agree?

*(2)* On average, how many of these bits does Eve know?

**My interpretation is the following:** ( Note : we will use EPR pair of $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$ ). Whatever Alice send her measured state ($|00\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$ or $|++\rangle$ or $|--\rangle$),
Eve sends random mixture of states :
$$ a|00\rangle+\; b|11\rangle+\; c|++\rangle+\; d|--\rangle \quad \text{where} \; |a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2=1 $$

Then for Ekert 91 protocol, we can consider the case when Alice sent state which collapsed into $|00\rangle$.

Then Bob will receive state " $a |00\rangle + b |11\rangle + c |++\rangle + d |--\rangle$ " from Eve

Since Bob need to get result $|0\rangle$ from Bob's qubit measurement so that Bob's bit not be discarded, 
The correlated collapsed state will be the following :
$$ a|00>+\; \frac{c}{\sqrt2}(\;|00>+\; |10>)+\; \frac{d}{\sqrt2}(\;|00>-\; |10>) \; \cdots (*) \quad \text{which} \; \text{must} \;\text{be} \;\text{normalized}$$

So I stuck at the point averaging out available arbitrary $a,b,c,d$ to get the possibility of Bob getting result $|0\rangle$

However, Now I'm curious about " Did I understood the phrase (Eve send a random mixture of qubit pairs) properly "

*My questions are*

1. Did I understood the phrase (Eve send a random mixture of qubit pairs) properly in the context of problem?
2. Is there any hint to average out the collapsed state (*) to get the average probability of Bob getting $|0\rangle$?

Thank you for reading my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is incorrect.

In the original scheme without Eve, Alice and Bob share the state
$$
|\Phi^+ \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|++\rangle + |--\rangle).
$$

In the question they use the Eve's state instead of $|\Phi^+ \rangle$.

The Eve's state is a random mixture of $|00\rangle, |11\rangle, |++\rangle, |--\rangle$. What you wrote is a superposition, not a mixture. It's a different thing.

Random mixture means that Eve picks the state $|E\rangle = |xx\rangle$ with probability $p_x$, for $x \in \{0,1,+,-\}$, where $p_x \ge 0$, $\sum p_x = 1$. So that, Alice and Bob use $|E\rangle$ instead of $|\Phi^+ \rangle$.

To calculate the quantities in question you can use the ordinary probability theory.

For example, let $|E\rangle = |00\rangle$.
If Alice and Bob measure in the standard basis $(S)$, they always get the same result. I.e. we can write that the probability of the same result is $P_{same}(SS|00) = 1$. Moreover, Eve knows the result in this case, i.e. the probability of her sure knowledge is $P_{leak}(SS|00) = 1$.
If Alice and Bob measure in the Hadamard basis $(H)$, they get the same result in 50% of cases, i.e. $P_{same}(HH|00) = 1/2$. In this case Eve can't know the result for sure, i.e. the probability of her sure knowledge is $P_{leak}(HH|00) = 0$. Note that measurements in different bases are discarded, and the bases $SS$ and $HH$ are equally probable. So that, the total probability in this case is $P_{same}(00) = 1/2\cdot P_{same}(SS|00) + 1/2 \cdot P_{same}(HH|00) = 3/4$. Similarly, $P_{leak}(00) = 1/2$.

To calculate the total answer we just use the law of total probability over all $|E\rangle = |xx\rangle$, for $x \in \{0,1,+,-\}$. That is,
$$
P_{same} = \sum_{x} p_x P_{same}(xx), 
$$
$$
P_{leak} = \sum_{x} p_x P_{leak}(xx). 
$$

Comment: Thank you I got it!